# Squid Content Manipulation

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I am interested in a solution for Squid Proxy to manipulate some html content. 
Eg. Add some arbitrary HTML/JS code to any page that is requested through the proxy.
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for ICAP or ECAP.  I have worked with proxies but have not done anything with either of these yet.

Content Adaptation (ICAP, ECAP, and others which are not as promising in my opinion)
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation